# Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

Estoy con esta versión de React Native:

```
root@hector-desktop:/home/hector/Documentos/LBS/proyectos/Foodandsave/app_foodie# react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.27.2
```

Cuando hago un `run-android` me devuelve este error:

```
root@hector-desktop:/home/hector/Documentos/LBS/proyectos/Foodandsave/app_foodie# react-native run-android --variant=release
(node:26097) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installRelease...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app 
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-paypal-wrapper 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices 
Parsing json file: /home/hector/Documentos/LBS/proyectos/Foodandsave/app_foodie/android/app/src/release/google-services.json

> Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/hector/Documentos/LBS/proyectos/Foodandsave/app_foodie/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:209: error: cannot find symbol
     @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
                                                ^
  symbol:   method isBlockingSynchronousMethod()
  location: @interface ReactMethod
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/hector/Documentos/LBS/proyectos/Foodandsave/app_foodie/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
66 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 64 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 0):

He borrado por completo node_modules y lo volví a instalar de vuelta.

También he cambiado la versión de react-native:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.54.2

Con esa versión me funcionó.